# The minimal possible number of homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have such questions in my qualifying exams.

> What is the minimal possible number of homomorphisms between two abelian
>   groups of order $900$?

I think since both are abelian group of order $900$, so we just need to take a look at generators of each group. I feel like for homomorphisms of such type shall give me the minimal number.

$$f: \mathbb{Z}_{900} \Longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_5$$ such that

$f(1) = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$ and $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$ is the only generator that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_5$ has. Hence, the minimal number should $1$.

Comment: I don't think $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$ is the only generator of the direct summand. Why not $(1,1,2,2,3,3)$, for example? As long as the number you pick in each indice is relatively prime to the moduls I think you will be fine.

I don't think the minimal number here will be one, though. Remember, we are looking for homomorphisms, not isomorphisms. $f(1)=(1,0,0,0,0,0)$ and $f(1)=(0,0,0,0,0,1)$ are unique homomorphisms, are they not? This is an interesting question though! If I have any more thoughts on it I'll let you know.

Comment: @Mathematical Mushroom Thanks for your help! This is becoming more interesting. Can you please vote up my question so others can see it?